# Elixir, how to cast from string to Ecto.Date?

Tags: string, date, casting, elixir

I have a date string with the format `"dd/mm/yyyy"` and I need to cast that value to `Ecto.Date` format.

I created a function like this, but I want to know if there is another way to do that.

```
defp format_birthday(birthday_string) do
  birthday = String.split(birthday_string, "/") |> Enum.reverse() |> Enum.join("-")

  Ecto.Date.cast(birthday)
end
```

Comment: `Ecto.Date` has been deprecated since Elixir 1.3. Are you sure you do not just want a `Date` struct?

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to have to depend on the Timex module:

```
birthday = "01/12/2012"

[dd, mm, yyyy] = String.split(birthday, "/")
{:ok, date} = Date.from_iso8601("#{yyyy}-#{mm}-#{dd}")
date

==> ~D[2012-12-01]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to parse date string into Date struct, you can use [timex](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/) library:

```
iex> "01/01/2019" |> Timex.parse!("{D}/{0M}/{YYYY}") |> Timex.to_date()
{:ok, ~D[2019-01-01]}
```

Comment: `{0M}` is equivalent to `{M}` when parsing.  It's when you are outputting strings, i.e. with `Timex.format()`, that `{0M}` does something different than `{M}`, i.e. `{0M}` pads single digit months with a leading `0` in the returned string.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are happy with a `Date` struct. In that case, I think [`Date.new/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html#new/4) is the nicest solution.

```elixir
"13/12/2019"
|> String.split("/")
|> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
|> (fn [day, month, year] -> Date.new(year, month, day) end).()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but for folks coming here more recently, we now have [`Date.from_iso8601/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.4/Date.html#from_iso8601/2) in elixir.

Use it like this (copied from the docs):

```
iex> Date.from_iso8601("2015-01-23")
{:ok, ~D[2015-01-23]}
```

There's also `Date.from_iso8601!/2` if you don't want to deal with the tuple and don't mind the function raising if your string is invalid.

This doesn't help the OP because this expects the more standard YYYY-MM-DD format of the string. I wanted to share it in case folks end up here from google and don't need the extra work of reformatting the date string.